# Apache URL Redirect

Tags: redirect, apache

My program is located at **http://server2.abcd.com/myprogram/**.

Our webmaster has set up a subdomain: **http://sub.abcd.com** for me. This subdomain will redirect to **http://server2.abcd.com/myprogram/**. The redirect configuration was done in the **httpd.conf**. Each time a user visit http://sub.abcd.com he will be redirected to http://server2.abcd.com/myprogram/

I don't want to confuse users. I want users to stay with the subdomain. For example, they do log in with **http://sub.abcd.com/login.jsp** rather than **http://http://server2.abcd.com/myprogram/login.jsp**. What should I do?

We use Unix, Apache and Tomcat5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask your web master to set up sub.abcd.com on server1 (and not as a redirect) and then if he/she can setup a ProxyPass and a ProxyPassReverse on server1 to server2. This is typical for web servers that are in front of application servers.

We have a similar setup and ProxyPass works well for us with applications resideing on other servers.

HTH,

KM

Answer (score 0):

In httpd.conf, you could, instead of the current redirection define the appropriate DocumentRoot for the VirtualHost corresponding to sub.abcd.com. The DocumentRoot should be wherever myprogram is located on the disk

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. The Apache server is on sever1 while my program is on server 2. Does this matter?

Comment: Yes, if they are on two different servers, the above suggestion unfortunately won't work as is